# Как получить массив, состоящий из значений полей массива классов?

Tags: matlab

Есть массив классов, например:

```
classdef MyClass
    properties
        field = 1;
    end
end
...
myClassArray = [];
for i = 1 : 100
    myclass = MyClass;
    myClassArray = [myClassArray myclass];
end
```

Нужно получить массив полей этих классов.
Можно сделать это так:

```
fields = zeros(length(myClassArray ), 1);
for i = 1 : length(myClassArray )
    fields(i) = myClassArray(i).field;
end
```

Но это выглядит несколько громоздко. Было бы идеально сделать это в одну строчку.
Если я пытаюсь сделать это так:

```
fields = myClassArray.field;
```

,значение переменной fields вычисляется как: fields==myClassArray(1).field;

Как можно получить массив полей класса негромоздким способом?

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Answer (score 0):

Решить проблему можно так:

```
fieldValues = [myClassArray.fieldName]
```

или, чтобы получить массив ячеек:

```
fieldValues = {myClassArray.fieldName}
```

Ответ был дан здесь:
[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44773519/how-can-i-get-an-array-of-field-values-for-each-instance-of-the-class)